# Getting a person's ORCID using the ORCID API

Tags: orcid

Best way to search a user's ORCID via name.

Is there any equivalent to what is essentially this page: https://orcid.org/orcid-search/search in the ORCID API ?

As in, and endpoint where I can just search as  `/api?name=john%20doe` and get back their id as the response ?

Note: The API seems to have documentation, but that documentation doesn't include, as far as I've seen, any guidance to actually using the API, only pages which explain how the api should be used, without giving you the actual urls, query parameters or example calls... :/

Answer (score 0):

Here you see how you have to get an Client_API ID and the secret for searching for ones name.

https://info.orcid.org/documentation/api-tutorials/api-tutorial-searching-the-orcid-registry/#easy-faq-2532

Answer (score -1):

Validating ORCID using javascript

```
function validOrcID(str) {
    /* ORCID format is XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. */
     if (!str) return false;
     testStr = new String(str);
     len = testStr.length;
     if (len!=19) return false
     dashTest = testStr.split('-');
     if (dashTest.length !=4) return false;
     if (dashTest[0].length !=4 || dashTest[1].length!=4 || dashTest[2].length!=4 || dashTest[3].length!=4) return false
     if (isNaN(dashTest[0]) || isNaN(dashTest[1]) || isNaN(dashTest[2]) || isNaN(dashTest[3])) return false
     return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think the question was about how to obtain a person's ORCID not about validating the string format on the client level…